# NestJS/Typeorm ormconfig.json is not being used

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I was just using typeorm with NestJS as usual. But it installed version 8.1.4 instead of my previously used 8.0.3. With the newer version I couldn't get the ormconfig.json working. I then checked and installed 8.0.3 and it worked again.
I have also tried with 9.0.0 and I couldn't get it to work their either.
Does somebody else has the same issue and maybe a temporary fix?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@nestjs/typeorm@8.1.0` and on `typeorm@^.3.0` is used, which [doesn't use the `ormconfig.json`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0). You'd need to update your code to make the ormconfig work (i.e. get rid of it and follow the 0.3.0 format).

Comment: how exacly does this work? I tried creating a ormconfig.js but it gives the same error, and I'm using "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1"

Comment: [As TypeORM's docs say](https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1) you need to have a [default export of a datasource](https://typeorm.io/changelog#deprecations), if this is to be used with the typeorm CLI. Otherwise, pass the config to `TypeormModule.forRoot/forRootAsync()`